# Why is $M_n(A)$ a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I'm trying to verify that for each von Neumann algebra $A$ the algebra of matrices with entries in $A$ is again von Neumann.

I do already know, that those kind of matrix algebras are again C-*-algebras.

I'd prefer a basic argument involving only weak or strong closedness over others.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is $M_n(A)$ von Neumann algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2706260/why-is-m-na-von-neumann-algebra)

Comment: @PrasunBiswas You got it the wrong way around. Also, that other question is now deleted.

Comment: yeah, both mine. I thought the first attempt to ask the question wasn't registered.

I already deleted the other one

Comment: @Arthur: I actually voted to close and marked it as duplicate because of the serial posting by OP.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas And you should've done that with the _other_ post, not this one. This is the original, the other was the duplicate. The duplicate is gone, so now there is only one left.

Comment: @Arthur: Yeah, I think I got my tabs switched that time. My bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A\subset B(H)$, you consider $M_n(A)\subset B( H^n)$. It is now a standard exercise, after noticing that $B(H^n)$ can be identified with $M_n(B(H))$,  that
$$
M_n(A)'=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} a&&0\\ &\ddots\\0&&a\end{bmatrix}:\ a\in A' \right\},
$$
and then that
$$
M_n(A)''=M_n(A'')=M_n(A). 
$$

Comment: this extends to any $n$, correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Beautiful argument. I remember proving this with strong convergence and that's a lot more difficult!

Comment: Thanks. Still, writing all the matrix manipulations would take a while for the one who never used these kind of argument.

Comment: Is there a way to prove this by interpreting $M_n(A)$ as $M_n\otimes A$ and applying properties of commutator over tensors? Oh, wait actually I'm not sure if $M_n(A)$ can be interpeted as $M_n\otimes A$.

Comment: Yes. What you need to do is to notice that the canonical isomorphism $[A_{kj}]\longmapsto \sum_{k,j} E_{kj}\otimes A_{kj}$ is normal; I think this is trivial, due to the fact that the sums are finite. You also need to convince yourself that there is a compatible isomorphism $H^n\to \mathbb C^n\otimes H$. This is usually glossed over, but the first time you need to sit down and compute.

Answer (score 0):

Strong convergence of a net in $M_n(A)$ is equivalent to entrywise strong convergence.

Assume $x_\lambda$ is a net in $M_n(A)$ converging strongly to $x \in B(H^n)$. Let $h,k \in H$ and $1 \leq i,j \leq n$. Let $\xi \in H^n$ be the vector which has $h$ in the $i$-th component and $0$ elesewhere, and let $\eta \in H^n$ which has $k$ in the $j$-th component and $0$ else. Then, in particular $\langle x_\lambda \xi, \eta \rangle \to \langle x \xi, \eta \rangle$. But this just means $\langle (x_\lambda)_{ij} h ,k \rangle \to \langle x_{ij} h, k \rangle$.

It follows that $x_{ij} \in A$.

Comment: Why does strong convergence in $M_n(A)$ imply strong convergence entry wise ?

Comment: First, you have to identify $M_n(A) \subset B(H^n)$ , when $A \subset B(H)$.

Comment: yes I can just inflate the embedding of $A$

Comment: I added the details to my answer.

Comment: I think you do show SOT-closedness, but could you also elaborate your statement about SOT-convergence being entrywise SOT-convergence?

Is the maximum norm on the direct sumt of n Hilbert spaces equivalent to the 2-norm(i.e. the norm induced by the inner product on the direct sum?)